# Meaning of curl response

Tags: http, curl, nginx, consul

I have downloaded the official consul image and I am running it behin an nginx load balancer.
When I send any http request using curl for ex

`curl my-consul-http-endpoint:8500/v1/catalog/nodes` I get the following back

```
*   Trying 172.29.225.62...
* Connected to my-consul-http-endpoint.com (172.29.225.62) port 80 (#0)
> GET /v1/session/list HTTP/1.1
> Host: my-consul-http-endoint
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 15:32:55 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 18633
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "56f72a9b-48c9"


    Connection #0 to host my-consul-http-endpoint left intact
```

What does the response suggest? Did I get connected to the consul server? Did the server return an error and inturn the nginx load balancer returned a 502?

Comment: I think this issue from your nginx server. Try to config again.

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: I'm sorry just I know when you config nginx wrong you will get 502 Bad Gateway. And I don't know what's wrong here with your case. Sorry

Comment: Please post your nginx configuration

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the consul client and connect to it with http://localhost:8500